# Remove thead tags from second page on when printing screen

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome

I am trying to print screen containing a table. Problem is, the thead tags are appearing on top of every page and overlapping the table data. Is there a way to just have the thead tags on first page on top of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it works if I just remove the  tags, lol